# NancyFx route seems broken if value has encoded forward slash

Tags: url-routing, urlencode, nancy

I have the following route:

```
Get["/details/{id:int}/{token}"]
```

It works as expected, except for when the token part includes an encoded forward slash ("/" = "%2f").

Example that throws a 404:

```
/details/1/QeH7oMezCNS3y%2fASnD4dGw%3d%3d
```

Example that works fine (no "/" included):

```
/details/1/QeH7oMezCNS3yASnD4dGw%3d%3d
```

If this is by design, are there any other characters I need to handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Greedy Segment (*) in your route:

```
Get["/details/{id:int}/{token*}"]
```

Comment: That worked for the slash, but now it's now working with an encoded space ("%2b"). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a known bug to do with [double encoding](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1280).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it differenty by writing my own URLencode and URLdecode functions which replace all "/" by another char which is never used in the token (e.g. ';') and then to HttpUtility.URLencode() on the edited token (the decoder function the other way around).

The Greedy Segment solution did not work easily, since I had this token in the middle of the route, not at the end, and other similar routes which might interfere with the Greedy Segment.

```
public static string UrlEncode(string path)
{
    return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path.Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Variables.PATH_SEP));
}

public static string UrlDecode(string path)
{
    return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(path).Replace(Variables.PATH_SEP, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
}
```